# Could not locate the assembly "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have updated System.Net.Http to 4.3.3 and since then I'm getting this error. One question is why is it still fetching System.Net.Http 2.2.9 files while it is not present in packages folder. System.Net.Http.Extensions is not in my References list. Where can I get the latest dll? Appreciate any help.

Here is the build log in Detailed mode

```
Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "mscorlib, 
Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, 
Retargetable=Yes". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this 
reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
6> For SearchPath"E:..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\net45".
6> Considered 
"E:..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\net45\mscorlib.winmd", but it didn't exist.
6>Considered 
"E:\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\net45\mscorlib.dll", but it didn't exist.
6> Considered 
"E:\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\net45\mscorlib.exe", but it didn't exist.
Considered "bin\Release\mscorlib.winmd", but it didn't exist.
6> Considered "bin\Release\mscorlib.dll", but it didn't exist.
6> Considered "bin\Release\mscorlib.exe", but it didn't exist.
6> Required by "System.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
```

Comment: what is your project type? Could you please share us some steps on a blank project to reproduce this issue so that we could reproduce this issue?

Comment: These are strongly typed assemblies, which are not picked from local directory, they will only be picked from GAC and to redirect to newer version you need Binding Redirect in the Assembly configuration file

Comment: As it seems, you still have reference to the "System.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.29.0", somewhere in your code, due to which its trying to load it and in process trying to load .Net 2.0 mscorlib, which is causing issue

Answer (score 1):

You can check that nuget packages exit or not
reinstall the packages using the Package Manager Console:

```
 Update-Package -reinstall
```

You need  to copy all dlls from `debug folder` to `release folder`.

One thing more: Make sure  your project files are not read-only. if it is read only then remove the read-only property by right clicking on the project folder and select properties. In the properties screen remove the read-only checkbox.

If that will not work then go through [This Link](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/299)   You will find details regarding your problem